# How to make the cmake-generated makefile stop at the first error

Tags: makefile, cmake

I use `cmake` to manage the build process of my project. Everytime when I want to rebuild it, what I need to do is simply `cmake .. & make -j8`, It works very well.

But I noticed that, the `make` command usually would like to output lots of errors then stopped finnaly.

It is a little annoying: Because for most of cases the first `error` is important and are essentialy the origin of your other `errors`.

How can I make cmake-generated **makefile stop at the first error** instead of continuing doing other stuffs?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

---

Update 1:
Under @Kitsu 's help can I realize the main duty is in `make -j8`. If I use `make -j1` instead, the `make` will stop at the first error.

But if we compile a big project, `-j8` usually makes sense... Is here any other way that can tell the fullset of `make` threads realize that, here is an error and stop themselves all at once?:)

Comment: Note you don't have to run `cmake` by hand every time.  You only have to run it one time, then you can run `make` many times.  If a CMakeLists.txt file changes then the next time you run `make` it will re-run cmake for you automatically.

Comment: Thans for pointing it out! I didn't know it till today...

Comment: Hi @MadScientist, just now I test your method! I use cmake 3.10.2 and GNU Make 4.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. But when I add a new src file in my project, It seems simply `make` didn't manage to catch up with it...

Comment: By "add a new src file" I assume you mean you edited your `CMakeLists.txt` file and added that file to the list of sources associated with an _add_executable_ or _add_library_ function?  I've been using CMake for 7 years and it definitely works, every time.

Comment: Ummmm, so sorry that I only works on `CMake` for 1 year... much shorter than yours:) Probably It is becuase I use lots of `aux_source_directory` to fetch my source list automatically which cause the `CMake` failed to refresh by itself.

Comment: Oh.  Yes.  Well, that's even explicitly stated in the documentation: _It is tempting to use this command to avoid writing the list of source files for a library or executable target. While this seems to work, there is no way for CMake to generate a build system that knows when a new source file has been added._  I highly discourage that kind of automated detection.  Is it really so hard, or do you really add new source files so often, that just adding them explicitly to the CMake files is not feasible?  It seems like a shortcut to save a bit of work up-front with major downsides long-term.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly guide! Obviously not, my project hasn't been so big to feel hard for writing a list of source files. I use `aux_source_directory` just because I don't know it is not good. But under the help of your words, apprently I should turn them into an explicit file list. :)

Answer (score 3):

`-Wfatal-errors` flag might do the thing for gcc. Also you may try to reduce parallelism for `make` itself (e.g. `make -j1`).

Comment: Thanks, I will try it later and come back soon.

Comment: Update 1 is maintained in the body of this question :)

Comment: I don't think generated makefiles are properly synced, so it might be not possible in general. Though, I don't know for sure. I think it's pretty common practice to give a user whole bunch of errors.